# two pages load in two div onclick event

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I would like to know how to load two pages in two different div at the same page, using onclick event.

HTML:

```
<a href="content.html">Content</a> 
<div id="FirstDiv"></div>
```

JavaScript:

```
$('a').click(function() {
    $('#FirstDiv').load($(this).attr('href'));
    return false;
});
```

---

So this is work with one page but how can i load another page at the same click event?

Answer (score 4):

Simply like this :

```
$('a').click(function() {
   $('#FirstDiv').load($(this).attr('href'));
   $('#SecondDiv').load('anotherURL.php');
   return false;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$("a").on("click", function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  $("#FirstDiv").load(this.href);
  $("#SecondDiv").load("url");
});
```