# load 2 pages in 2 different divs simultaneously on onlick of 1 button

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

```
$('#menuhome').click(function(){
            $('#leftcolumncontainer').load('pages/homemenu.php');

        });
```

the above will load the home menu on left when on its own it ok..now i want to add this

```
 $('#menuhome').click(function(){
                $('#middlcolumncontainer').load('pages/homecontent.php');

            });
```

the code above will load the home content in the middle

what i want to achieve is when i click the button home menu will load in the left and home content will load in the center..but this code does something odd when i click the button the content load in the center and in the left so i tried something like this

```
$('#menuhome').click(function(){
                $('#leftcolumncontainer').load('pages/homemenu.php');
                $('#middlcolumncontainer').load('pages/homecontent.php');
            });
```

same thing happens my question is how to achieve what i want with this code what is wrong

`"UPDATE"`

```
$.when($('#leftcolumncontainer').load('pages/homemenu.php', $('#middlcolumncontainer').load('pages/imagegallerycolumn.php'))).done(function(x){
            return(x);

        });
```

this is the code i am working on right now

**update**

```
$('a.menuhome').click(function(e) {
                 $.when($('#leftcolumncontainer').load('pages/homemenu.php')).then(function() {
            $.ajaxSetup({
                url: "pages/homecontent.php",
                success: function(result) {
                    $("#middlcolumncontainer").html(result);
                }
            });
            $.ajax();
                  });});
```

this is the new code i used the only problem here is that the middlecontainer does not load homecontent

***homecontent page:***

```
<div id="middlecontainerimagegallerycolumn" >
    <div id="imagegallerycorner">
        <div id="bigimage_container"></div>
        <div id="bigimage_description"></div>
        <div id="carousel_container">
        <div id="left_scroll"><img src='images/left.png' /></div>
        <div id="carousel_inner">
        <ul id="carousel_ul" >
        <li><a href='#'><img src='images/image1.jpg' id="1"/></a></li>
        <li><a href='#'><img src='images/image2.jpg' id="2"/></a></li>
        <li><a href='#'><img src='images/image3.png' id="3"/></a></li>
        <li><a href='#'><img src='images/image4.jpg' id="4"/></a></li>
        <li><a href='#'><img src='images/image5.jpg' id="5"/></a></li>
        <li><a href='#'><img src='images/image6.png' id="5"/></a></li>
        <li><a href='#'><img src='images/image7.png' id="5"/></a></li>
        <li><a href='#'><img src='images/image8.png' id="5"/></a></li>
        </ul>
        </div>
        <div id='right_scroll'><img src='images/right.png' /></div>
        </div>

    </div>
</div>
```

***js:***

```
$("#bigimage_container").ready(function() {
        document.getElementById("bigimage_container").style.background = 'url('+$('#carousel_ul li:first img').attr("src") +') ';
        document.getElementById("bigimage_container").style.backgroundPosition = "center center";
        document.getElementById("bigimage_container").style.backgroundRepeat = "no-repeat";
        document.getElementById("bigimage_container").style.backgroundSize = "100% 100%";
        document.getElementById("bigimage_description").innerHTML = $('#carousel_ul li:first img').attr("src");
        });
    $(document).ready(function() {
        //move he last list item before the first item. The purpose of this is if the user clicks to slide left he will be able to see the last item.
        $('#carousel_ul li:first').before($('#carousel_ul li:last'));


        //when user clicks the image for sliding right        
        $('#right_scroll img').click(function() {
            document.getElementById("bigimage_container").style.background = 'url(' + $('#carousel_ul li:nth-child(3) img').attr("src") + ') ';
            document.getElementById("bigimage_description").innerHTML = $('#carousel_ul li:nth-child(3) img').attr("src");
            //alert($('#carousel_ul li:nth-child(2) img').attr("src"));
            document.getElementById("bigimage_container").style.backgroundPosition = "center center";
            document.getElementById("bigimage_container").style.backgroundRepeat = "no-repeat";
            document.getElementById("bigimage_container").style.backgroundSize = "100% 100%";
            //get the width of the items ( i like making the jquery part dynamic, so if you change the width in the css you won't have o change it here too ) '
            var item_width = $('#carousel_ul li').outerWidth() + 10;

            //calculate the new left indent of the unordered list
            var left_indent = parseInt($('#carousel_ul').css('left')) - item_width;

            //make the sliding effect using jquery's anumate function '
            $('#carousel_ul:not(:animated)').animate({
                'left': left_indent
            }, 100, function() {

                //get the first list item and put it after the last list item (that's how the infinite effects is made) '
                $('#carousel_ul li:last').after($('#carousel_ul li:first'));

                //and get the left indent to the default -150px
                $('#carousel_ul').css({
                    'left': '-150px'
                });


            });
        });

        //when user clicks the image for sliding left
        $('#left_scroll img').click(function() {
            document.getElementById("bigimage_container").style.background = 'url(' + $('#carousel_ul li:first img').attr("src") + ') ';
            document.getElementById("bigimage_description").innerHTML = $('#carousel_ul li:first img').attr("src");
            document.getElementById("bigimage_container").style.backgroundPosition = "center center";
            document.getElementById("bigimage_container").style.backgroundRepeat = "no-repeat";
            document.getElementById("bigimage_container").style.backgroundSize = "100% 100%";
            var item_width = $('#carousel_ul li').outerWidth() + 10;

            /* same as for sliding right except that it's current left indent + the item width (for the sliding right it's - item_width) */
            var left_indent = parseInt($('#carousel_ul').css('left')) + item_width;

            $('#carousel_ul:not(:animated)').animate({
                'left': left_indent
            }, 100, function() {

                /* when sliding to left we are moving the last item before the first list item */
                $('#carousel_ul li:first').before($('#carousel_ul li:last'));

                /* and again, when we make that change we are setting the left indent of our unordered list to the default -150px */
                $('#carousel_ul').css({
                    'left': '-150px'
                });
            });


        });

    });
```

Comment: can you come up with a plunker for the problem?

Comment: where you can showcase your problem...you can even try jsfiddle

Comment: i cant because as you can see i load two different pages as far as i know you cant load something like this on fiddle..i will just describe it..when i click home the code above loads the page ok on its own..i mean when the other is not in the code when they are together the problem is that the home content is loaded in the middle(which is ok) and is loaded in the left as well(not ok becuase left is for home menu)

Comment: got you...will come up with an answer in a min

Comment: have a look at this link [Stack Overflow][1] , this may help


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15767983/two-pages-load-in-two-div-onclick-event

Comment: When/where do you load the javascript?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to check the asynchronous behaviour of load, this [working fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kmkVu/)
will help you

Code Snippet:

```
$('#menuhome').click(function(){
    $.when($('#leftcolumncontainer').load('http://fiddle.jshell.net/webdevem/JfcJp/show/')).done(function(x){
    $('#middlcolumncontainer').load('http://www.yahoo.com');
});
});
```

Do note that www.yahoo.com wont get loaded because of cross site scripting but in the console you will get to know that it tried to load this url instead of the top one

Comment: sir the left is doing good what will do to make the middle show?it says undefined function on line $.when($('#leftcolumncontainer').load('http://fiddle.jshell.net/webdevem/JfcJp/show/')).done(function(x){ i think you accidentally put `.` in the code

Comment: Don't really need the `$.when` call -- could just put the second load call inside the first one's `complete` handler to achieve the same effect.

Comment: @NateWhittaker have you seen my code above is that what you mean by put inside the first one?when i do that what happens is the middle content(home content) is loaded in the middle and left container... can you show me what you mean or further explain?

Comment: nothing to say for downvoting it means it was not done logically

Answer (score 2):

`load()` is just a shortcut for `$.get` that automagically inserts the loaded content into the DOM, and it does so whenever the content is ready.

To load the content of two pages and insert both at the same time, we'll have to move away from `load()` and use `$.get` instead so we can manually insert the content when both pages have loaded

```
$('#menuhome').click(function(){
    $.when(

        $.get('pages/homemenu.php'),
        $.get('pages/homecontent.php')

    ).done(function(menuData, contentData) {

        $('#leftcolumncontainer').html(menuData.shift());
        $('#middlcolumncontainer').html(contentData.shift());

    });
});
```

This does both ajax calls, and only when both are successful and have completed is the content is inserted at the same time in both elements.

Answer (score 1):

Simply like this :

```
$('#menuhome').click(function() {
   $('#leftcolumncontainer').load($(this).attr('pages/homemenu.php'));
   $('#middlecolumncontainer').load('pages/homecontent.php');
   return false;
});
```

Have a look at this [Stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15767983/two-pages-load-in-two-div-onclick-event)

Comment: I think you mean `.attr('href')`

Answer (score 1):

Give this a shot to force loading the resources serially:

```
$(function(){$('#menuhome').click(function(){
    $('#leftcolumncontainer').load('pages/homemenu.php', function(){
        $('#middlcolumncontainer').load('pages/homecontent.php');
    });
})});
```

However, it's not clear why you're observing the behavior you are. As far as I can tell, it should work as you'd expect. A reduced test case would help cancel out any environmental factors...

Comment: what you do you mean  by environmental factors?like i said when i do it like the one above in my question only one page is load the home content loaded in both left and middle i will try your code and be back in a minute

Comment: I guess what I mean is that if this code doesn't work, there may be some other code elsewhere you haven't shared with us that is causing the unexpected behavior.

Comment: i think the only problem is with the code for the home because the other one are working ok loading one page only same code just one .load line...home on the other hand has two needs to load the left home menu and middle home content by the way your load didnt even loaf left or middle

Comment: Does it make sense to you that my code would fail? Can you debug it to find the specific point of failure?

Answer (score 1):

Your first try should simply work, assuming you're fine with loading both contents simultaneously and inserting them when they become available.

```
$('#menuhome').click(function(){
    $('#leftcolumncontainer').load('pages/homemenu.php');
    $('#middlecolumncontainer').load('pages/homecontent.php');
});
```

[<kbd>**DEMO**</kbd>](http://jsfiddle.net/crad1rx0/)

I think the middle content may not be loading due to a typo.
You've written `#middlcolumncontainer` without an `e`.

Otherwise, it could be a same origin policy issue. Are you testing on a web server or on your local file system?

EDIT:

Let's go back to the basics then.
The following works on the file system for me.

*index.html*

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div>
        <div id="left"></div>
        <div id="middle"></div>
        <input type="button" id="menuhome" value="menu home" />
    </div>
    <script>
        $(function() {
            $('#menuhome').click(function() {
                $('#left').load('pages/menu.html');
                $('#middle').load('pages/content.html');
            });
        });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

*pages/menu.html*

```
<div>menu</div>
```

*pages/content.html*

```
<div>content</div>
```

Comment: Updated with complete example in files on the filesystem. I don't think the error lies in code you're listing.

Comment: ive seen the fiddle can you tell me whats the problem if not the code?

Comment: my middle page is an image gallery i will update the code for image gallery

Comment: The content loads fine and shows (albeit broken) img links when I replace the pages/content.html with your home content page. Where do you include the js? What exactly do you do and what exactly goes wrong?